# Upgrading the libraries to non-vulnerable versions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Any suggestions for non-vulnerable versions of Bootstrap and Jquery.
Currently using the Bootstrap v3.3.7 and jQuery v1.10.2 and jQuery UI - v1.10.1 - 2013-02-28.
After finishing the penetration test, they recommend upgrading the libraries to non-vulnerable versions. Please advise which version should I upgrade Bootstrap and JQuery . Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript vulnerability is a strange game; The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: More specific: there's no such thing as "non-vulnerable" javascript (other than no javascript, hence the quote above).  What your "consultant" meant was to upgrade to *latest versions* to remove any known vulnerabilities.

Comment: I suggest the latest. And if possible keep versions up to date. New vulnerabilities are found constantly.